# How to trigger event when an object is rearranged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In a website (not mine) there's a table containing values. I'm making a somewhat add-on to this site. I have a jQuery script that scrapes the values of that table,then adds a column to that table and calculates a certain value for each row. These values change when the rows on the table gets rearranged (the user can drag and drop the rows around), I want to know how to detect that event so I'll know when to recalculate values.

The way I do this is I have an object `x` that contains several `<tr>` with ids.

For example: `x = [ <tr id="1">, <tr id="2">, <tr id="3">]`

I need to trigger an event when the elements of x gets rearranged, for example if x becomes `[ <tr id="2">, <tr id="1">, <tr id="3">]`

Comment: Without directly looking to solve this problem, what do you want to accomplish with loading HTML into an object?

Comment: There's a table on a website, and my script adds a column to that table, the values on the added column changes when the rows get rearranged, so I want   to know how to get such event so that I can recalculate the values when the rows get rearranged

Comment: So what you are really after is a way to watch for DOM changes on your table, ie `tr`s being rearranged? Also are you using something like jQuery UI's `sortable`, as that offers callbacks after elements have finished being dragged and sorted

Comment: You load this from a database, am I right? Why not just ask the database if a change occurs?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes

Comment: @GerritLuimstra No, the website is an existing site,  I don't have access to the database, I just scrape the values of the table from the frontend

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing Alright

Comment: @PatrickEvans The website wasn't made by me so I don't have access to stuff like that, I just scrape values from the frontend, I'm kind of just making an add-on to the site.

Comment: @PatrickEvans the user can drag and drop the rows around and rearrange them as they want, what I want is that everytime the user rearranges the rows, the values of the added column get  updated immediately

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the object at the start. Every time any function activates that *could* affect the object, check to see if each element in the object is equal to the element in the copied object. 
 If it is, keep going. 
If not, do whatever you need to, then assign the current object with the new positions to the copy variable you made at the beginning, and keep going.

Comment: What if I don't know what functions could affect the object? The website is an existing site (not developed by me) and I don't have much idea what happens on the backend, there's no api either. All I can do is enter jquery commands through the console